# (Python) Retrieve the sunrise and sunset times from Google

Tags: python, time, google-search

**Hello!**
I recently went to the LACMA museum of art, and stumbled upon this [clock](http://unframed.lacma.org/2014/11/24/solving-mystery-cm%E2%80%99s-artwork-jim-campbell%E2%80%99s-untitled-sun). Basically it uses a light sensor to determine the percent of the day that has passed. This means sunrise would be 0.00% and sunset would be 100%. I wanted to create a easier version of this, having a program Google the sunset and sunrise times for the day and work from there. Eventually this would all be transferred to a Raspberry Pi 3 (another problem for another day), therefore the code would have to be in Python. Could I maybe get some help writing it?

## TLDR Version

I need a Python program that googles and returns the times of the sunset and sunrise for the day. Mind helping?

Comment: Sunset/Sunrise time is almost the same every year on a particular day. So you can first try to build your clock with static data then later when it's working you can switch to real time google data.

Comment: You could youse this APIs: http://sunrise-sunset.org/api

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty but it should work, just use your coordinates as the parameters.

From their website "NOTE: All times are in UTC and summer time adjustments are not included in the returned data."

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

def get_sunrise_sunset(lat, long):
    link = "http://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=%f&lng=%f&formatted=0" % (lat, long)
    f = requests.get(link)
    data = f.text
    sunrise = data[34:42]
    sunset = data[71:79]
    print("Sunrise = %s, Sunset = %s" % (sunrise, sunset))

    s1 = sunrise
    s2 = sunset
    FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
    tdelta = datetime.strptime(s2, FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1, FMT)
    daylight = timedelta(days=0,seconds=tdelta.seconds, microseconds=tdelta.microseconds)
    print('Total daylight = %s' % daylight)

    t1 = datetime.strptime(str(daylight), '%H:%M:%S')
    t2 = datetime(1900, 1, 1)
    daylight_as_minutes = (t1 - t2).total_seconds() / 60.0
    print('Daylight in minutes =  %s' % daylight_as_minutes)

    sr1 = datetime.strptime(str(sunrise), '%H:%M:%S')
    sr2 = datetime(1900, 1, 1)
    sunrise_as_minutes = (sr1 - sr2).total_seconds() / 60.0
    print('Sunrise in minutes =  %s' % sunrise_as_minutes)

    ss1 = datetime.strptime(str(sunset), '%H:%M:%S')
    ss2 = datetime(1900, 1, 1)
    sunset_as_minutes = (ss1 - ss2).total_seconds() / 60.0
    print('Sunset in minutes =  %s' % sunset_as_minutes)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_sunrise_sunset(42.9633599,-86.6680863)
```

Comment: I am don't understand "why using SUN on Earth time ?", Sun not in earth, every system got local clock, check jupiter, mars time etc. it's bullshit...

Comment: @dsgdfg Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: If I wanted to use the data to calculate the amount of minutes of sun in a day, so the difference of sunset and sunrise how would I do that? I have tried playing around with it a bunch, but to no avail.

Comment: @Beta_Penguin I edited my initial answer to accommodate your last question about total daylight.

Comment: Thank you one again, but how could I get the time in minutes as an integer? So I could do certain functions to it?

Comment: @HexxNine, I think this will be my final request, but how would I find the same thing but for just the sunrise time? I need both for the code to work.

Comment: @Beta_Penguin I'm not sure what you mean. Can you explain more?

Comment: Of course, so for my code I am going to need to length of the day in minutes (which you have graciously provided), but also I need the time of the sunset and sunrise in minutes as well. For example 1:32 AM, would be 92 minutes.

Comment: @Beta_Penguin updated, but remember the times are in UTC